# View in UiTableViewCell turns transparent at selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls, selection

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a Red `UIView` which turns transparent when i select the `UITableViewCell`.

I don´t want that to happen. Is there a way to keep the color of the `UIView` at selection?

Only configuration regarding that view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";
    DetailsCell *cell = (DetailsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: kCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code that you have?

Comment: Code added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add tag to your view.

```
yourview.tag = 3;
```

And than in your tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method add this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get the cell which is selected
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //set tempView color of selected cell bcoz when cell selected all view color is gone
    UIView *tempView=[selectedCell viewWithTag:3];
//set your color whatever you want
    tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(112/255.0) green:(136/255.0) blue:(213/255.0) alpha:1];
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also do this using selecting your cell selection color to NONE. Put this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: It´s almost this. The problem with this is that when i select the UIView still gets transparent, only when i deselect it turns to the color chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the setHighlighted methods of UITableViewCell to undo any changes that the default behaviour is doing.

Comment: Solution - in the cell:                                                                            
        override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
  imageView.backgroundColor = = UIColor.white
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom background view with color you want. The place you do this would vary on how you're configuring your cell.

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = // Your color (cell.backgroundColor perhaps);
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
```

Comment: I don´t want to change the UITableViewCell selected color. It´s the view i have inside the UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to show the selection (with a blue color) but leave your views with the colors you gave them, you can set the selectionStyle to nil, as you did in your answer (or set it in IB), and then do this in code:

In RDCell.m:

@implementation RDCell

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the table view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label1.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    if ([self.selectedPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }else{
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.selectedPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```